# What is the difference between STOXX and STOXXE?

Tags: index

Could anyone explain the difference between STOXX and STOXXE?  Which is the right index for benchmarking European stocks?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding where you see these monikers?  There are actually dozens of [STOXX indices](http://www.stoxx.com/indices/types/benchmark.html).

Comment: Tal, let's say .stoxx and .stoxxe, two rics from reuters.com

Comment: There are a set of indices for Europe and for countries in the Eurozone, so .STOXX50 includes Sweden, Switzerland & UK, .STOXX50E doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Stoxxe would be the benchmark for European stocks in Eur

Different data providers are using different symbols.

- Sx5e biggest 50 European Eur stocks
- Sx5p biggest 50 pan European stocks
- Sxxp biggest 60@ pan euro stocks - 200 large cap 200 mid cap and 200 small caps
- Sxxe would be all Eur stocks put of the sxxp - around 380 names

Comment: I am not sure about the pan euro stocks, can you explain?

Comment: Pan European - GBP,CHF,Sek,NOK,EUR,DKK from a currency Point of view